# FOR /F from command, command is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, directory

I wrote a simple script that loops inside a stream of file names, i am getting 
  piped from dir command, as followed by this url [For /F command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b ^"???? *.sql^"') do (
    call :runscript "%%G" %dbname% %op% %dbinstance%
    rem stop further processing if execution failed and return error code
    if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1
)
```

unfortunately  i am getting this error:

> error 'dir /b "???? *.sql"' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Remove `^` left to both `"`. Just `|`, `&`, `>` must be escaped in __DIR__ command line executed by __FOR__ in a background process started with `cmd.exe /C` and the specified command line.

Comment: No need to use a `FOR /F` in this instance.  You could just use the base `FOR` command. `FOR %%G IN ("???? *.sql") do (`

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```
@echo. > ..\Downloads\Tables.sql
@echo. > ..\Downloads\Columns.sql
dir ..\Downloads\*.sql
 Volume in drive C is Windows

Directory of C:\Users\anorh\Downloads

2018-02-17  06:01 PM                 3 Columns.sql    
2018-02-17  06:01 PM                 3 Tables.sql

               2 File(s)              6 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  327,567,941,632 bytes free
```

Using 'for' command syntax for working with files (so the value in the parens is a path and filter).

```
for %A in (..\Downloads\*.sql) do ( @echo %~fA )
C:\Users\anorh\Downloads\Columns.sql
C:\Users\anorh\Downloads\Tables.sql
```

Using for syntax for working primarily within files (but in this case the file content is the output of the command).

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=" %A in (`dir /ON /B C:\Users\anorh\Downloads\*.sql`) do ( @echo %~fA )
C:\Users\anorh\Documents\Columns.sql
C:\Users\anorh\Documents\Tables.sql
```